# Cant write to database with cakePHP

Tags: php, sql-server, database, cakephp

I am new to cakePHP and am just starting to use it for my new job.
I have created an edit_company action in my Orders Controller. I updated the acos table to allow this action. Now the problem is, I can't access any sort of 'edit' action. It says "You are not authorized to access that location" whenever I try to acccess any action that writes or updates database. edit,edit_products,edit_shipping, etc...

The view action works just fine.

This was not happening before.

Heres a bit of the code:

```
class OrdersController extends AppController{
        public $uses = array('Order');
    public $hideActions = array('campaign','customer','shipping','review_order','place_order','products','payment','confirmation','cancel','edit_status','edit_order_type','edit_products','edit_tax','add_product','cancel_shipping_label','track_label','view_label','reprint_label','edit_shipping','create_shipping_label');
    public $components = array('Payflow','Printer');
    public $actionMap = array(
        'create' => array('add','create','campaign','customer','shipping','review_order','place_order','payment','products'),
                'read'=> array('index', 'view', 'display','confirmation','track_label','search'),
        'update' => array('edit','cancel','edit_status','edit_order_type','edit_products','edit_company','edit_tax','add_product','cancel_shipping_label','reprint_label','edit_shipping','create_shipping_label'),
        'delete' => array('delete','back_orders_by_state')
    );
    public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('permissions','gen_acos');   
    }
    public function permissions(){
        $this->Acl->allow('Admin','Controllers/Orders');
        $this->Acl->allow("Sales","Controllers/Orders",'read');
        $this->Acl->allow("Sales","Controllers/Orders",'create');
        $this->Acl->allow("Sales","Controllers/Orders",'update');
        $this->Acl->deny("Shipping","Controllers/Orders",'update');
        $this->Session->setFlash("Permissions Updated.");
        $this->redirect("/orders/");
    }
    public function edit_shipping($id){
        $sm_conditions = array();
        if(!$this->Acl->check(array('User' => array('UserID' => $this->Auth->user("UserID"))), 'Controllers/Orders','delete')){
            $sm_conditions['Restricted'] = 1;
        }
        $shipping_method_ids = $this->Order->ShippingMethod->find("list",array("conditions"=>$sm_conditions,"fields"=>array("ShippingMethodID","ShippingMethodName")));
        $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);

        $this->set("order",$order);
        $this->set("shipping_method_ids",$shipping_method_ids);
        if($this->request->is('put')){
            if($this->Order->save($this->data,null,array("ShippingAddress","ShippingMethodID"))){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Order Shipping Updated.");
                $this->Order->Note->create();
                $this->Order->Note->save(
                    array("Note"=>array('OrderID'=>$id,"UserID"=>$this->Auth->user("UserID"),"NoteBody"=>"Order Shipping Information updated.","CreatedDate"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))
                );
                $this->redirect("/orders/view/$id");
            }
        }else{
            $this->request->data = $order;
        }
    }


    public function create_shipping_label($id){
        $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
        $this->set("order",$order);
        if($this->request->is('put')){
            $this->Order->save(array(
                "Order"=>array(
                    "OrderID"=>$id,
                    "LabelPrinted"=>false,
                    "OrderStatusID"=>2,
                    "Notes"=>(!empty($this->data['Order']['Notes']))?$this->data['Order']['Notes']:null
                )
            ));
            $this->Session->setFlash("A new shipping label will be created momentarily.");
            $this->Order->Note->create();
            $this->Order->Note->save(
                array("Note"=>array('OrderID'=>$id,"UserID"=>$this->Auth->user("UserID"),"NoteBody"=>"New shipping label will be created. ".((!empty($this->data['Order']['Notes']))?$this->data['Order']['Notes']:null),"CreatedDate"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))
            );
            $this->redirect("view/".$id);
        }else{
            $this->request->data = $order;
        }
    }
    public function cancel($id){
        $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            //Check if note given
            $this->Order->Note->data = $this->data;
            if($this->Order->Note->validates()){

                //Delete from Call table
                $this->loadModel("Call");
                $this->Call->deleteAll(array('Call.OrderID'=>$id));
                //Add a note
                $user_id = $this->Auth->user("UserID");
                $this->Order->Note->create();
                $this->Order->Note->save(
                    array("Note"=>array('OrderID'=>$id,"UserID"=>$user_id,"NoteBody"=>"Order Canceled. ","CreatedDate"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))
                );
                $this->Order->Note->create();
                $this->Order->Note->save(
                    array("Note"=>array('OrderID'=>$id,"UserID"=>$user_id,"NoteBody"=>"Reason For Cancellation: ".$this->data['Note']['NoteBody'],"CreatedDate"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s")))
                );
                //Create a refund request if payment type is in TxType (1,2,3,7,11,9)
                $txTypes = array(1,2,3,7,11,9);
                $paid = 0;
                foreach($txTypes as $txType){
                    $payments = Set::extract("/Payment[TransactionTypeID=$txType]/PaymentAmount",$order);
                    $paid += array_sum($payments);
                }
                if($paid>0){
                    $this->Order->refund($id,$paid);
                }
                //Change Status to Cancel (4) & LabelPrinted = 0
                $this->Order->save(array("Order"=>array("OrderID"=>$id,"LabelPrinted"=>0,"OrderStatusID"=>4)));
                //Update the total price
                $this->Order->updateOrderTotal($id);
                $this->Session->setFlash("Order was successfully canceled.");
                $this->redirect("/orders/view/".$id);
            }
        }
        $this->set("order",$order);
    }
    public function edit_products($id){
        $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
        $this->set("order",$order);
        if($this->request->is("post")){
            $error = false;
            while($error==false && ($oe=array_shift($this->request->data['OrderEntry']))){
                if(!$this->Order->OrderEntry->save(array("OrderEntry"=>$oe))){
                    $error = true;
                }
            }
            if($error==false){
                $this->Session->setFlash("Products Updated.");
                $this->Order->updateOrderTotal($id);
                $this->redirect("/orders/view/$id");
            }
        }


}
    public function edit_company () {

    }

    public function edit ($id=null) {
        $order = $this->Order->read(null,$id);
        $this->set("order",$order);
        if($this->request->is("post")){
                $error = false;
                while($error==false && ($oe=array_shift($this->request->data['OrderEntry']))){
                        if(!$this->Order->OrderEntry->save(array("OrderEntry"=>$oe))){
                                $error = true;
                        }
                }
                if($error==false){
                        $this->Session->setFlash("Products Updated.");
                        $this->Order->updateOrderTotal($id);
                        $this->redirect("/orders/view/$id");
                }
        }

    }
```

Could anyone help me with this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only giving non authenticaded users permission to access two actions:

```
    public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('permissions','gen_acos');   
    }
```

Add the new actions or log the user in before accesing the actions:

Giving permission to not authenticated users to your new actions:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('permissions','gen_acos','edit_products','edit','cancel','create_shipping_label','edit_shipping');   
    }
```

If you don't want to grant access to non authenticated users to these actions login before trying to access them.

You can check more about Auth [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html)

Also check [this](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) example that is part of the Blog Tutorial

Comment: I'm glad it helped, remember you can always fav my answer or like it :)